# if my image src is null then i dont want show image what i want to do?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am getting image source from an API and some image paths are `null`, if so then I don't want to show the image at all.

This is my code but it doesn't work when path is `null`. What do I do to fix this?

```js
${logoPath.map((C) => `<img alt="" class="production-logo" src="${logo.concat(C)}">`)}
```

Comment: you need to check if there is an image or not

```${logoPath?.map((C) =>......... ```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is `filter` you `logoPath` before `map`.

```
${logoPath.filter(x=>!!x).map(....)}
```